# How do I upload image in android emulator to Whatsapp app

Tags: emulation

I can't upload image PC to android emulator
I want to upload image in PC to android Emulator. There is a gallery button that in connected with Whatsapp. If I send photo to another Whatsapp account then save this photo. When I save the photo then I send this photo to another whatsapp account. I want to upload image with my PC gallery not emulator gallery.
Thank You...